# Unit Testing using Karma and jasmine

Tags: angular6, karma-jasmine

Hello performing testing on my login.component.spec.ts file and I am getting an error of

> Failed: Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: toastr is not defined
>   and not able to understand where the problem is

```
`login.component.spec.ts `:
 import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed ,inject} from '@angular/core/testing';
    import {DebugElement} from '@angular/core';
    import {FormsModule,FormGroup,ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
    import { LoginComponent } from './login.component';
    import { By,BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import { NgxLoadingModule } from 'ngx-loading';
    import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
    import { routes } from '../../app.routing';
    import { P404Component } from '../../views/error/404.component';
    import {P500Component} from '../../views/error/500.component';
    import {RegisterComponent} from '../register/register.component';
    import {ForgotPasswordComponent} from '../forgot-password/forgot-password/forgot-password.component';
    import {ResetpasswordComponent} from '../resetpassword/resetpassword.component';
    import {ChangepasswordComponent} from '../changepassword/changepassword.component';
    import {DefaultLayoutComponent} from '../../containers/default-layout/default-layout.component' ;
    import {AppAsideModule,AppBreadcrumbModule,AppHeaderModule,AppFooterModule,AppSidebarModule,
    } from '@coreui/angular';
    import { PerfectScrollbarModule } from 'ngx-perfect-scrollbar';
    import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
    import { HttpClientModule,HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http'; 
    // import { ToasterService } from '../../services/toaster.service';
    import { ToasterService } from '../../services/toaster.service';
    describe('LoginComponent', () => {
      let component:LoginComponent ;
      let fixture: ComponentFixture<LoginComponent>;
      let de:DebugElement;
      let el:HTMLElement;
      beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
          declarations: [ LoginComponent,
    RegisterComponent,
    ForgotPasswordComponent,
    ResetpasswordComponent,
     ChangepasswordComponent,
    DefaultLayoutComponent,
    P404Component,
    P500Component],
          imports:[
            HttpClientModule,
            RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
             FormsModule,
             BrowserModule,
             NgxLoadingModule,
             ReactiveFormsModule,
             AppAsideModule,
             AppBreadcrumbModule,
             AppHeaderModule,
             AppFooterModule,
             AppSidebarModule,
             PerfectScrollbarModule,
           ] ,
           providers:[ ToasterService, { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/' }],           
        })
        .compileComponents().then(() =>{
          fixture = TestBed.createComponent(LoginComponent);
          component = fixture.componentInstance;
          de=fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('form'));
          // el=de.nativeElement;
        });
      }));    
      beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(LoginComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        fixture.detectChanges();
      });    
      it('should create', () => {
        expect(component).toBeTruthy();      
      });
    });
```

Getting ouptut as this:

> Failed: Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: toastr is not defined
>   ReferenceError: toastr is not defined
>       at ToasterService.setting (webpack:///./src/app/services/toaster.service.ts?:27:9)
>       at new ToasterService (webpack:///./src/app/services/toaster.service.ts?:15:14)
>       at _createClass (webpack:///./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js?:8710:20)
>       at _createProviderInstance (webpack:///./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js?:8684:26)
>       at resolveNgModuleDep (webpack:///./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js?:8647:21)
>       at NgModuleRef_.get (webpack:///./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js?:9355:16)
>       at resolveDep (webpack:///./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js?:9720:45)
>       at createClass (webpack:///./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js?:9600:32)
>       at createDirectiveInstance (webpack:///./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js?:9477:20)
>       at createViewNodes (webpack:///./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js?:10697:36)

toaster.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
declare var toastr:any;
@Injectable()
export class ToasterService {   
  constructor() { 
    this.setting();
  }
  Info(title:string)
  {
    toastr.info(title);
  }    
  Success(title:string)
  {
    toastr.success(title);
  }    
  Error(title:string){
    toastr.error(title);
  }    
  setting()
  {
    toastr.options = {
      "closeButton": false,
      "debug": false,
      "newestOnTop": false,
      "progressBar": false,
      "positionClass": "toast-top-right",
      "preventDuplicates": false,
      "onclick": null,
      "showDuration": "300",
      "hideDuration": "1000",
      "timeOut": "1800",
      "extendedTimeOut": "1000",
      "showEasing": "swing",
      "hideEasing": "linear",
      "showMethod": "fadeIn",
      "hideMethod": "fadeOut"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: kindly share `./src/app/services/toaster.service.ts` also

Comment: Hi the toaster.service.ts is added abvoe

Comment: Hi this problem got solved as their was one dependency reamining to add

Comment: @SanchitaRaut : Good. Can u please close the question as well